# Migrate System.Security/IdentityModel to OWIN/Katana Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, katana

I want to migrate my security infrastructure to OWIN/Katana but i'm not very familiar with it. I hope someone can give me a ride in the right direction. Currently i use .net fwk 4.5, mvc 5 and the features in System.Security/IdentityModel. The authentication is done against ADFS 2.0 (i want to configure it in owin), i use claims transformation and session management (where is it placed and how it's done in owin) and authorization is done by filters (is still the same in owin?).
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at blog post by [Vittorio Bertocci](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/)  that shows how to secure webapi.
Lots of sample that can be applied to ADFS https://github.com/Azure-Samples to secure using OWIN.